# Generate models and serializers from JSON with null value and missing attributes?

Tags: java, c#, flutter, dart

i am trying to generate a class model from an APIs JSON response (List), i use some service for auto-generation, and everything seems to work fine until the response JSON start returning attributes with a **null value** and the other thing is that some attributes are **missing** when i call the APIs. EX:

response JSON:

```
[
    {
        "persone": {
            "name": "To John",
            "age": 15
        },
        "group": "ipsum"
    },
    {
        "persone": {
            "name": "To John",
            "age": null
        },
        "group": "ipsum"
    },
    {
        "persone": {
            "name": "To John"
        }
    }
]
```

in the above example, the age attribute is null, and the group attribute is missing in the last object of the list.

My question is how do you create an appropriate class model in that case handling the **null** and the **missing attribute**?

Comment: have you tried create model from quicktype .io

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes i did, but it is not working in the cases i mentioned above

Comment: i think you can work around it on the UI side if the list[index].persone.age == null or list[index].group == null then show ui SizedBox.shrink() also can you show us the code where you gonna show this data

Comment: i thought about that, but i am trying to avoid adding logic in the UI part (smart UI)